# Issue using mod_rewrite/rewite map and urls with spaces in them

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

we are doing a move from a server product to a cloud product and unfortunately they are changing the URLs on us. To help mitigate the issue of links to specific items in the new location I have generated a mapping of all the URLs. While the ones without spaces in them work the ones with spaces do not and I end up with a 404 message

This is the code I have in my `httpd.conf` file

```
  RewriteCond ${redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}} ^.+$
  RewriteMap redirects /confs/redirects.example.com/URLs
  RewriteRule .* https://${redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}} [redirect=temporary,last,qsdiscard]
```

This is an example of the mapping

`"redirects.example.com/confluence/display/ADS/New Tech Tip - Pidgin Settings" newsite.vendor.com/wiki/spaces/ADS/blog/2011/10/12/8487166/New+Tech+Tip+-+Pidgin+Settings`

As you can see I have tried encapsulating it in `"` as well as escaping the space with `\` and converting the spaces to `%20`, as I have seen in the other posts, however nothing seems to work.

I can see that the *spaces* are encoded to `%20` in the error log when it gives me a 404 message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Aside:_ Do you need to store the hostname in the map file? Is this not a constant?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *spaces* are delimiters in TXT map-type files and I don't believe there is a way to escape literal spaces in the map file itself.

The literal spaces are encoded as `%20` in the HTTP request (they must be in order to form a valid HTTP request), but the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is %-decoded. So you are trying to use a string with literal spaces to perform the lookup which is going to fail.

The solution would to store the %-encoded URL in the TXT map file (ie. *spaces* are encoded as `%20`) and use the %-encoded URL-path to make the lookup. We can extract the %-encoded URL from `THE_REQUEST` server variable.

So, the map file should look like this:

```
redirects.example.com/confluence/display/ADS/New%20Tech%20Tip%20-%20Pidgin%20Settings newsite.vendor.com/wiki/spaces/ADS/blog/2011/10/12/8487166/New+Tech+Tip+-+Pidgin+Settings
```

> ```
> RewriteCond ${redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}} ^.+$
> RewriteMap redirects /confs/redirects.example.com/URLs
> RewriteRule .* https://${redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}} [redirect=temporary,last,qsdiscard]
> ```

Note that the `RewriteMap` directive itself is not part of the `RewriteRule` / `RewriteCond` rule. You appear to have sandwiched it in the rule itself (it might "work" but it's not correct). Also, you are not declaring the map-type.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteMap redirects "txt:/confs/redirects.example.com/URLs"

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/[^?\s]*)
RewriteCond ${redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}%1} (.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1 [R=302,L,QSD]
```

The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) captures the %-encoded URL-path from `THE_REQUEST` server variable. (`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line from HTTP request headers and contains a string of the form `GET /url?query HTTP/1.1`.)

The captured %-encoded URL-path is then used in the 2nd *condition* (as part of the call to the rewrite map) using the `%1` backreference.

The result of the rewrite map lookup is also captured in the `%1` backreference (overwriting the earlier backreference) in the 2nd *condition*. This is then used in the *substitution* string - no need to call the rewrite map a second time.

I used the shorthand flags, but that's just personal preference. Obviously this should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended.